# What am I, really?

Tags: riddle

What am I…

Really?

What is emotion…

besides signals to the brain?

Your heart can't really think,

So is your "heart" really your mind?

I think it is.

Some people mistake me as a pessimist.

But I'm really a…

I'm really a…

What am I?

Really?

Comment: What's with the really's?

Comment: Is the fourth line supposed to start with a lower case letter?

Comment: Your a Questionist!!!

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm certainly a Questionist :). Not right, but so close, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too sure, but...

> You're a realist?  Maybe even a scientist.  Dunno

The part about the brain makes me think both the first and second.  The heart line can also be made to fit both answers.  However, the first answer really fits the pessimist clue.

> Side note, why is the riddle symmetric?

Comment: How is it symmetric?

Comment: It just appears like that, with the line lengths

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say you were a Skeptic. It's pretty much in the same line as AJL's response, but I think this doubt about reality relates better to classical, greek skepticism.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skepticism#Philosophical_skepticism for reference.